# Ruby on Rails/Devise smtp.rb segmentation fault

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, smtp, devise, gmail

I have done quite a bit of research on this issue and have not been able to solve my issue.  I am using Rails 3.0.3, Ruby 1.8.7 (patchlevel 334), Apache, Passenger 3.0.7 and the Devise gem 1.1.8.  Also, I am using gmail for sending out emails.  When I attempt to send a password reset I am getting an error in my Apache error_log:

[Tue Nov 01 19:40:31 2011] [error] Premature end of script headers: users
[ pid=9371 thr=3084437904 file=ext/apache2/Hooks.cpp:822 time=2011-11-01 19:40:31.664 ]: The backend application (process 9569) did not send a valid HTTP response; instead, it sent nothing at all. It is possible that it has crashed; please check whether there are crashing bugs in this application.

From my research, I found one reason that it could be due to Ruby on Rails looking for a version of OpenSSL that is buggy.  I tried the suggestion of adding this to my .bashrc file:

export RUBYOPT="-ropenssl"

Also, I tried to update my SMTP configuration in my production.rb to not use TLS:

:enable_starttls_auto => false

My complete SMTP configuration:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => '<domain>' }
  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :enable_starttls_auto => false,
  :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
  :port => 587,
  :domain => <domain>,
  :user_name => <username>,
  :password => <password>,
  :authentication => "plain" 
}
```

None of the suggestions I have found seem to have worked.  I am not sure where to go from here as these are the only suggestions and fixes I have found.  It does work without any issues on my development machine.  Which is running the same versions of all the above except Apache/Passenger, which I do not us locally.

Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by upgrading the Devise gem to version 1.4.8.  However, after upgrading this I got an error "undefined method `new_session_path'."  I then upgraded to Devise version 1.4.9 and everything is working fine now.  Hope this helps someone.

Mike